# ASP literal inside a repeater footer template

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I think this is not possible by trying to add a literal into a footer template of a repeater so that I can fill it later on...

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Literal ID="panelFooter" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can data bind the `Text` attribute to the result of a method in your code-behind. In this example we are going to display the total number of products in the footer:

```
<FooterTemplate>
  Total number of products: 
  <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# GetTotalNumberOfProducts() %>' />
</FooterTemplate>
```

In the code-behind we are going to create a method that calculates the number and returns it for the `Literal` control.

```
protected string GetTotalNumberOfProducts()
{
  return 42.ToString();
}
```

Notice that we don't need to find the control by its ID. We are just returning s `string` and the data binding syntax will call our method in code-behind and put the result inside the control.